# CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied - pyspark

Tags: java, python, pyspark, anaconda

I seek your help as I am attempting to run the following codes however i am presented with the following error stating that the python home path is access denied.

I have tried to run the browser, cmd in admin mode and execute it and i have also change directory permission to give everyone full control however error doesnt go away.

```
import random
NUM_SAMPLES = 100000000
def inside(p):
 x, y = random.random(), random.random()
 return x*x + y*y < 1
**count = sc.parallelize(range(0, NUM_SAMPLES)).filter(inside).count()**
pi = 4 * count / NUM_SAMPLES
print('Pi is roughly', pi)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2b827abd567e> in <module>
     13  x, y = random.random(), random.random()
     14  return x*x + y*y < 1
---> 15 count = sc.parallelize(range(0, NUM_SAMPLES)).filter(inside).count()
     16 pi = 4 * count / NUM_SAMPLES
     17 print('Pi is roughly', pi)

C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in count(self)
   1126         3
   1127         """
-> 1128         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
   1129 
   1130     def stats(self):

C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in sum(self)
   1117         6.0
   1118         """
-> 1119         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
   1120 
   1121     def count(self):

C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in fold(self, zeroValue, op)
    988         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
    989         # to the final reduce call
--> 990         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
    991         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
    992 

C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py in collect(self)
    887         """
    888         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 889             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    890         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    891 

C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1284         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1285         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1286             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1287 
   1288         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     96     def deco(*a, **kw):
     97         try:
---> 98             return f(*a, **kw)
     99         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    100             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

C:\spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 22, DESKTOP-MRGDUK2, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\developer\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.7.6-h60c2a47_2": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:444)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 15 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1989)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:1977)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1976)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:956)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2155)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2144)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2116)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2137)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2156)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2181)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1004)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:388)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1003)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\developer\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.7.6-h60c2a47_2": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:441)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:444)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:444)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Are you running pyspark locally or on a cluster? Did you accidentally start your spark server with some authentication requirements?

Comment: i am running it locally @JasonChia

Comment: are you able to start the pypsark session correctly? I.e. with all the configs and parameters along. Can you see your session on the Spark UI? Personally never came across this error before though. Can you try the solution from this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604884/spark-2-1-0-bin-hadoop2-7-python-createprocess-error-5-access-is-denied

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this issue by setting the environment variable "PYTHON_HOME" to my installed python.exe filepath!

Answer (score 3):

**Env variables for PySpark**:

1. Add Spark's bin folder to **PATH** variable:

   Windows: *D:\SW\Spark\spark-3.0.3\bin*

   Unix: *export PATH=$HOME/Spark/bin:$PATH*
2. Create **PYSPARK_PYTHON** with path to python to ensure executors can run Python 3.5+:

   Windows: *D:\Python\Python37\python.exe*

   Unix: *export PYSPARK_PYTHON=$HOME/anaconda/bin/python3*

Additionally, if you're using Jupyter instead of cli for pyspark:

3. Create **PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON** variable

   Windows: *PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter*

   Unix: *export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter*
4. Create **PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS** variable to pass notebook parameter to Jupyter and link to new instance of pyspark:

   Windows: *PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'*
   For windows, don't add pyspark in the end

   Unix: *export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook' pyspark*

Comment: When you say `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter` do you mean `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=<path to Jupyter notebook>` ? And if so can you give an example of what this path looks like.

Comment: When you say `For windows, don't add pyspark in the end` can you explain what you mean better? Actually I think you can delete this sentence and it would be come less confusing?