# How to solve error caused during conversion of Dictionary to Dataframe in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Spark 3.4 with Python 3.10. I am trying to convert following data in Python dictionary format into a Pyspark dataframe.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Row, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('MyApp').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'],
            'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],
            'deaths': [523, 52, 25, 616, 43, 234, 523, 62, 62, 73, 37, 35],
            'battles': [5, 42, 2, 2, 4, 7, 8, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9],
            'size': [1045, 957, 1099, 1400, 1592, 1006, 987, 849, 973, 1005, 1099, 1523],
            'veterans': [1, 5, 62, 26, 73, 37, 949, 48, 48, 435, 63, 345],
            'readiness': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
            'armored': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            'deserters': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
            'origin': ['Arizona', 'California', 'Texas', 'Florida', 'Maine', 'Iowa', 'Alaska', 'Washington', 'Oregon', 'Wyoming', 'Louisana', 'Georgia']}
```

I tried various approaches but none of them seem to be working.

Here is one of the approach I followed:

1. Convert dictionary of values as lists into list of dictionaries

```
raw_data_size = len(raw_data['origin'])
raw_data_keys = raw_data.keys()
mapping_list=[]
mapping = {}
for i in range(raw_data_size):
    for key in raw_data_keys:
        mapping[key]=raw_data[key][i]
    mapping_list.append(mapping)
    mapping={}
```

Output of `mapping_list[:1]`

```
[{'regiment': 'Nighthawks',
  'company': '1st',
  'deaths': 523,
  'battles': 5,
  'size': 1045,
  'veterans': 1,
  'readiness': 1,
  'armored': 1,
  'deserters': 4,
  'origin': 'Arizona'}]
```

2. Create Schema

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('regiment', StringType(), True),
    StructField('company', StringType(), True),
    StructField('deaths', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('battles', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('size', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('veterans', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('readiness', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('armored', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('deserters', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('origin', StringType(), True)
])
```

3. Create dataframe out of it. **Getting error in this step**

```
army=spark.read.schema(schema).json(mapping_list)
```

Error stack:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 1
----> 1 army=spark.read.schema(schema).json(mapping_list)

File C:\software\programming\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py:418, in DataFrameReader.json(self, path, schema, primitivesAsString, prefersDecimal, allowComments, allowUnquotedFieldNames, allowSingleQuotes, allowNumericLeadingZero, allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, dateFormat, timestampFormat, multiLine, allowUnquotedControlChars, lineSep, samplingRatio, dropFieldIfAllNull, encoding, locale, pathGlobFilter, recursiveFileLookup, modifiedBefore, modifiedAfter, allowNonNumericNumbers)
    416 if type(path) == list:
    417     assert self._spark._sc._jvm is not None
--> 418     return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    419 elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    421     def func(iterator: Iterable) -> Iterable:

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File C:\software\programming\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:169, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    167 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    168     try:
--> 169         return f(*a, **kw)
    170     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    171         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o99.json.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.HashMap and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:722)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:551)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:404)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:362)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Please let me know what could I be missing or doing wrong and how can I ensure it works smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Some of the other approaches I tried are:

1. `spark.createDataFrame(mapping_list).show()`

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o174.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 27) (host.docker.internal executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

2. `spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in mapping_list).show()`

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o153.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 26) (host.docker.internal executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

3. I also tried converting it into pandas dataframe and loading it but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the good track by defining your schema! One of the ways you can do this, is by making your input data (your dictionary) in a format that the `spark.createDataFrame` method can use.

Let's reuse your code

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([
    StructField('regiment', StringType(), True),
    StructField('company', StringType(), True),
    StructField('deaths', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('battles', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('size', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('veterans', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('readiness', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('armored', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('deserters', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('origin', StringType(), True)
])

raw_data = {'regiment': ['Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Nighthawks', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Dragoons', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts', 'Scouts'],
            'company': ['1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd', '1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd','1st', '1st', '2nd', '2nd'],
            'deaths': [523, 52, 25, 616, 43, 234, 523, 62, 62, 73, 37, 35],
            'battles': [5, 42, 2, 2, 4, 7, 8, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9],
            'size': [1045, 957, 1099, 1400, 1592, 1006, 987, 849, 973, 1005, 1099, 1523],
            'veterans': [1, 5, 62, 26, 73, 37, 949, 48, 48, 435, 63, 345],
            'readiness': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
            'armored': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
            'deserters': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 4, 24, 31, 2, 3, 2, 3],
            'origin': ['Arizona', 'California', 'Texas', 'Florida', 'Maine', 'Iowa', 'Alaska', 'Washington', 'Oregon', 'Wyoming', 'Louisana', 'Georgia']}
```

By turning your `raw_data` (which is a dictionary of lists) into a list of dictionaries, you can then use it in the `createDataFrame` method:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([dict(zip(raw_data, col)) for col in zip(*raw_data.values())])

df.show()
+-------+-------+-------+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----+--------+
|armored|battles|company|deaths|deserters|    origin|readiness|  regiment|size|veterans|
+-------+-------+-------+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----+--------+
|      1|      5|    1st|   523|        4|   Arizona|        1|Nighthawks|1045|       1|
|      0|     42|    1st|    52|       24|California|        2|Nighthawks| 957|       5|
|      1|      2|    2nd|    25|       31|     Texas|        3|Nighthawks|1099|      62|
|      1|      2|    2nd|   616|        2|   Florida|        3|Nighthawks|1400|      26|
|      0|      4|    1st|    43|        3|     Maine|        2|  Dragoons|1592|      73|
|      1|      7|    1st|   234|        4|      Iowa|        1|  Dragoons|1006|      37|
|      0|      8|    2nd|   523|       24|    Alaska|        2|  Dragoons| 987|     949|
|      1|      3|    2nd|    62|       31|Washington|        3|  Dragoons| 849|      48|
|      0|      4|    1st|    62|        2|    Oregon|        2|    Scouts| 973|      48|
|      0|      7|    1st|    73|        3|   Wyoming|        1|    Scouts|1005|     435|
|      1|      8|    2nd|    37|        2|  Louisana|        2|    Scouts|1099|      63|
|      1|      9|    2nd|    35|        3|   Georgia|        3|    Scouts|1523|     345|
+-------+-------+-------+------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----+--------+
```

**EDIT**: Ahh damn I didn't completely look at the stack trace in your question, and just now noticed a fundamental piece in one of your tryouts.

```
Cannot run program "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

This is not a Spark problem (that first "other approach" you put down here seems like it should work). If you look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674431/possible-causes-of-java-io-ioexception-createprocess-error-5), it seems like something might be wrong with your `C:\ProgramData\anaconda3` executable. Try and change your permissions on that executable like one of the answers from that SO post :)

Comment: I tried following this approach but I am still getting an error ( Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.showString. ). Could this be a bug/installation issue? Its really weird because data frames created from external csv's are working fine.

Comment: I've added an edit to my answer. Seems like I didn't fully read all of your stack traces, sorry. I hope you get it fixed now!

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me! It was a Pyspark issue. To be specific I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414394/createprocess-error-5-access-is-denied-pyspark